# Naive prediction using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, prediction, difference

Suppose, I have a data set:

```
ix    m_t1   m_t2
1     42     84
2     12     12
3     100    50
```

then, we can use

```
df = df[['m_t1', 'm_t2']].pct_change(axis=1).mul(100)[1]
```

to calculate the difference between `m_t1` and `m_t2` in %

like

```
diff
100
0
-50
```

I would like to apply this difference on `m_t2` to get `m_t3_predicted`

```
m_t3_predicted
168
12
25
```

How can I do it?

P.S. Is there any name for the algorithm?

Comment: Please, clarify your question with an example of the result you want to achieve.

Comment: @sentence is it clear enough?

Comment: Now, yes, it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_diff=df[['m_t1', 'm_t2']].pct_change(axis=1).mul(100).drop(columns=["m_t1"])
```

```
df_diff

    diff
0   100.0
1   0.0
2   -50.0
```

Rename column in df_diff:

```
df_diff.columns=["diff"]
```

Concat dataframes:

```
df_result=pd.concat([df,df_diff],axis=1)
```

Then calculate:

```
df_result["m_t3_predicted"]=df_result["m_t2"]+df_result["diff"]/100*df_result["m_t2"]
```

Result:

```
    ix  m_t1    m_t2    diff    m_t3_predicted
0   1   42      84      100.0   168.0
1   2   12      12      0.0     12.0
2   3   100     50     -50.0    25.0
```

Comment: And what is the name of the method?